# Mock two get responses with different result

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'am trying to mock two same get requests but with different result. My goal is to test second exception (except requests.exceptions.RequestException) but I can't make it work so that first requests.get pass and second requests.get fail to "connect" and therefore to reach second exception. Is that even possible? Thx!

```
try:
    tenants = requests.get('https://hostname_1')     

    for tenant in tenants:

        try:
            a = requests.get('https://host_2')

            try:          
                some_function(arguments)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(e)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

here is what I tried:

```
@patch("argo_probe_poem.poem_cert.requests.get")
@patch("argo_probe_poem.poem_cert.requests.get")
def test_raise_request_exception(self, mock_requests1, mock_requests2):
    mock_requests1.side_effect = pass_web_api
    mock_requests2.side_effect = requests.exceptions.RequestException

    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as e:
        utils_func(self.arguments)

    self.assertEqual(e.exception.code, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `Mock` object return different values and/or raise different exceptions on different calls by specifying an iterable as the `side_effect` attribute.

An excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

> If you pass in an iterable, it is used to retrieve an iterator which
> must yield a value on every call. This value can either be an
> exception instance to be raised, or a value to be returned from the
> call to the mock...

So your test code should roughly look like:

```
@patch("argo_probe_poem.poem_cert.requests.get")
def test_raise_request_exception(self, mock_requests):
    mock_requests.side_effect = pass_web_api, requests.exceptions.RequestException

    with self.assertRaises(requests.exceptions.RequestException) as e:
        utils_func(self.arguments)
```

Comment: I had to change my pass_web_api function but your solution worked, thank you!